# Marshalling char arrays in the Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, pinvoke

On the compact framework (3.5) I have a pinvoke as follows:

```
[DllImport("VAMDll.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "openLiteSpatial")]
public static extern int OpenLiteSpatial(byte[] mode, byte[] data, byte[] capture, IntPtr callback);
```

For the following native function sig:

```
int openLiteSpatial(char *mode, char *data, char *capture, void callBack(char *, char *));
```

Passing parameters inwards works fine like this:

```
Native.OpenLiteSpatial(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Mode.FunctionalLocation), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(functionalLocation), Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(capture), Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback));
```

But in my callback I have to do some strange transformations on the callback parameter strings:

```
public delegate void LiteSpatialCallback(string attributeData, string geoCoordinate);
    public static void Callback(string attributeData, string geoCoordinate)
    {
        byte[] decodedAttributeData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(attributeData);
        byte[] decodedGeoCoordinate = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(geoCoordinate);

        attributeData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedAttributeData, 0, decodedAttributeData.Length);
        geoCoordinate = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedGeoCoordinate, 0, decodedGeoCoordinate.Length);
    }
```

I have tried specifying the Charset on the DllImport attribute, and using byte[] arrays (which causes the callback to not get called at all), and specifying various MarshalAs options.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to pass IntPtrs for the delegate parameters, then use the Memory windows to see exactly what's coming back in them.  Is it a pointer to data?  A pointer to a pointer? The data itself?  Is it Unicode or ASCII?  All these could be determined by walking the addresses returned.  You could then either just manually copy from that target, or you could re-work the P/Invoke and/or delegate signature based on your findings.